# HTML2canvas script not outputting correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to output all table rows into a div using HTML2canvas. It works fine, all the rows output as images into the specified div. The problem i'm having is that the order of some of the output images in the div aren't the same as the order of the table rows in the HTML. It seems as though certain rows are being converted into an image before other rows. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and whether there is a fix for this? A snippet of my code is below

```
var n = 0;


function nextStep() {
    m++;
    if (m >= 19) return;
    // some body
    allTrs.each(function() {
        html2canvas($(this), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element

                n = n + 1;

                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $('#outputimages').append('<img style="display:block; width:700px;" src="' + myImage + '" class="' + n + '" />');
                nextStep();
            }
        });
    });
}
nextStep();
```

Comment: html2canas is async!

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: You dont know what asynchron is?